# How to change the value of a variable in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if (%1)==(/?) (       
echo Hilfe zur Verwendung des Programms:
echo.Aufruf des Programms mit 3 Startwerten oder mit keinen Startwert.
echo.Dabei muss jeder Startwert eine Zahl groesser als 0 sein!
goto ende
)



if (%1) == () (
    echo.anfangskapital eingeben:
    set /p anfangskapital=
) else (
    set /a anfangskapital= %1

)

:checkAnfangskapital
    if %anfangskapital% LEQ 0 (
    echo Anfangskapital muss groesser 0 sein.
    set /p anfangskapital=
    goto checkAnfangskapital
)



if (%2) == () (
    echo.zinssatz eingeben:
    set /p zinssatz=

) else (
    set /a zinssatz = %2
)

:checkZinsatz
    if %zinssatz% LEQ 0 (
    echo Zinsatz muss groesser 0 sein.
    set /p zinssatz=
    goto checkZinsatz
)

if (%3) == () (
    echo.Anzahl Jahre eingeben:
    set /p jahre=

) else (
    set /a jahre = %3
)

:checkJahre
    if %jahre% LEQ 0 (
    echo Anzahl Jahre  muss groesser 0 sein.
    set /p jahre=
    goto checkJahre
)

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%jahre%) DO   set /a anfangskapital = !anfangskapital! *(1+(%zinssatz%/100)) 


 echo %anfangskapital% 

:ende
pause
```

The value of `anfangskapital` is always the same, it won't change its value in the `for` loop. I don't know why. I tried it with `%%` and with `!!` but it doesn't change anything.
How can I change the value of `anfanskapital`?

Comment: Cannot give you a solution unless you show us all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a endkap=%anfangskapital%
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%jahre%) DO set /a endkap=!endkap! *(1+(%zinssatz%/100)) 
echo %endkap% REM 1000
```

Comment: endkap is not changing because zinssatz isn't changing. Post more code that shows what you're doing with zinssatz. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why are you expecting afangskapital to change when zinssatz doesn't change in your loop? All you're doing is running the same evaluation jahre times. You don't specify what you're trying to do. But you should probably put `%%a` (the value of your loop iteration, between 1 and jahre) into your equation somewhere.